# How can I execute a script after calling window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that redirects the user to another page. I want to load some content into a div on the new page after the new page has fully loaded. How can I do this. The following doesn't work.

```js
function goToPage() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/info';
    $('.my_class').load('my/url/path/with/content/to/load');
}
```

The newly loaded page `http://www.mypage.com/info` contains the following div:

```html
<div class="my_class"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to do it on the new page, you can't run javascript on the old page after you have redirected, period.

Comment: @adeneo is correct. Is there a reason why you're not passing the page to load as a query string parameter and loading that in the target page's `onload`?

Answer (score 19):

Redirect to the new page, but append a hash signal to the URL.

```
function goToPage() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/info#load-stuff;
}
```

Then on load of the target page, evaluate the URL checking for that hash signal.

```
function pageLoad() {
    if (window.location.hash === "#load-stuff") {
        $('.my_class').load('my/url/path/with/content/to/load');
    }
}
```

If your application is using jQuery it'd look something like:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.hash === "#load-stuff") {
        $('.my_class').load('my/url/path/with/content/to/load');
    }
});
```

That's the rough idea at least.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to pass data to your page you are redirecting to would be to set some url parameters.

For example:

```
window.location.href - "http://youpage.com/?key=value"
```

When that page loads you could have a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var my_param = getUrlParameter('key');
    if(my_param == "value"){
//do your stuff here
}

});


var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just run

```
$('.my_class').load('my/url/path/with/content/to/load');
```

on this page: http://www.mypage.com/info.

When you do `window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/info';` you're redirecting to another page. Nothing after that line will happen. You have to instead run the code after that line on the page that's loaded.

Comment: i like this answer best, the question doesn't give any reason why both statements can't be executed on their own pages respectively

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the other answers, you won't be able to perform any script instructions from your original site. Instead of using PHP to create the content statically, you could also use HTML fragments as arguments, e.g. like this:

---

```
// in the original page:
function goToPage() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/info#my/url/path/with/content/to/load';
}
```

---

```
// in http://www.mypage.com/info:
$( document ).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.hash)
        $('.my_class').load(window.location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know about window.location.hash. I guess I should RTFM.

Comment: Looks like an XSS vulnerability though...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a few different ways. Try leveraging the localstorage API and passing info or content with a name and value pair (or a few of them) and unpack it on the receiving end.

On the page you're redirecting to, check for the localstorage key, and then load the contents of it (the aforementioned name and value pairs) into a div.

As an alternative, you can write one script file that you can deploy to several pages; do a check on window.location.href and conditionally load script accordingly. If you're on the redirected page, you can run whatever script you like. The nice part about doing it this way is that you're still working with one JS file - no need to fragment your code (assuming, of course, that the pages you're working with are all on the same site).

You don't need to do anything with php if you don't want to, or hashes... there's a few nifty tools that will do the trick if you can leverage HTML5 and its associated APIs.

Comment: Tnx for the new idea. I have slightly different case. I'm also using the location.href to call a new page, but that page actually forces a download of the file and hence, after the download is done - I still stay on the original page. I want to recognize when is this page loading/download finished and the original page has the "control" again. This seems like the only answer with a useful suggestion for my case, so +1. I didn't find any events that would be able to recognize the end of such call.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location = '#/MyPage';
setTimeout(function() {
   //MyCode To Run After PageLoad
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: This worked for me, although I needed to make sure the timeout was 1000ms instead of 500

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting the browser with `window.location.href` and I'm afraid as you are purely just changing the browser's location, you can't have any affect/input on the page you are moving to (unless you use query string parameters and then create content with something like PHP (myurl.php?newcontent=whatever)  )

Comment: You can use query string parameters to influence any JavaScript on the new page, too, as long as it's programmed to look for them.

Comment: Yes that was actually my suggestion? Apologies if it was unclear, but why downvote [a valid answer]?

Comment: You stated you can't have any input on the page you're moving to, unless you create content with something on the server side. You _can_ have input on the page you're moving to: provide a query string (or a #fragment on the end of the URL as other answers have mentioned), and JavaScript on that page can read that query string (or fragment) for input. Such a method doesn't require _anything_ special to happen on the server side at all, so you don't need it to generate content.

Comment: Um.. when did I mention server side? And especially /needing/ it? To express that this was also possible with javascript would have sufficed.

Comment: Mentioning server-side: _"and then create content with something like PHP"_. Needing it: _"I'm afraid as you are purely just changing the browser's location, you can't have any affect/input on the page you are moving to (unless you use query string parameters and then create content with something like PHP)"_ which I read as: can't provide input to the next page, unless you use query strings to inform server-side technology which generates content on the new page.

Comment: keyphrase: "which I read as". I'm only trying to help, which is the entire reason for this site, right? My input was valid and correct (although subject to interpretation, it seems).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34807/discussion-between-jonathan-hobbs-and-alfie)

Answer (score 1):

Once you redirect you can no longer execute scripts on that page, as the page is unloaded.

Try this,

redirect page:

```
function goToPage() {
window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/info;
}
```

mypage.com/info:

js:

```
$('.my_class').load('my/url/path/with/content/to/load');
```

html:

```
<div class="my_class"></div>
```

I hope this helped you out, and let me know if you need further assistance!