# Automatically login to gmail using javascript code

Tags: javascript, autofill

I am new to javascript programming and I am trying to write some javascript code that can automatically fill up and submit the login form of Google. The code below works fine when the current page is https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.hk%2F%3Fgfe_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DaaHnU563DIaL8Qeu-oG4Cw%26gws_rd%3Dssl&hl=en

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for(var k=0;k<inputs.length;k++) { 
    var input = inputs[k] ;
    var type = input.getAttribute('type');
    if(type == 'email')
        input.value = "abc@gmail.com";
    if(type == 'password')
    input.value = "1234";
} 

var forms=document.getElementsByTagName('form'); 
forms[0].submit();
```

Then I tried to add some codes so that if the browser is currently on another webpage, the program will direct to Google and login automatically. Here is what I have written:

```
function autoSubmit(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for(var k=0;k<inputs.length;k++) { 
        var input = inputs[k] ;
        var type = input.getAttribute('type');
        if(type == 'email')
            input.value = "abc@gmail.com";
        if(type == 'password')
        input.value = "123";
    } 

    var forms=document.getElementsByTagName('form'); 
    forms[0].submit();
}

document.location.href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.hk%2F%3Fgfe_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DaaHnU563DIaL8Qeu-oG4Cw%26gws_rd%3Dssl&hl=en";
window.onload=autoSubmit();
```

However, this doesn't work. It seems that the function autoSubmit() is executed before the Google webpage has been completely loaded. Could anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048338/how-can-i-execute-a-script-after-calling-window-location-href

Comment: You are _calling_ the function instead of assigning just the function _reference_ to the event … but even if you corrected this, I doubt it will work: Changing location will “refresh” the window object in a way that your handler should not survive.

Comment: you need to use tampermonkey or greasmonkey to run your own script on gmail.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into Google APIs?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

First, you are correct that the `autuSubmit` function is being called early:

```
window.onload=autoSubmit();
```

What you are doing is calling `autoSubmit` *at that time* and assigning its value to `window.onload`.

What you mean to do is this:

```
window.onload=autoSubmit;
```

Note that I removed the parens `()`.  That assigns a function reference.

**However...**

This still won't do what you wish it will do.

When you change the page -- the `location.href` (which should be `window.location.href`, btw), you load a new page and the current information -- all JavaScript, the `window.onload` handler and everything -- is thrown away.

In short, there is no way, using standard programming, to make this happen.

If you are trying to make something with for yourself, and you aren't trying to make it work for everyone, you can use a `userscript`, which can run under Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.  Userscripts let you add extra code to run on a web page, but again, it will only run for you.