# Calling javascript function from one page to add element on second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call a javascript function from one page to add an element in  another page. The function is being called but the problem is that when I redirect it to the new page, code after that doesn't execute.

```
window.func = function() {

location.href = 'second.html';
var div = document.getElementById("div1");
var button = document.createElement("button");
div.appendChild(button);
}
```

This function is called by first page and the changes after the redirection should be made in second page. I can't use document.ready function for page2 because I don't want the changes to occur every time page2 loads rather I want changes to take place only after button from page1 is pressed.

Comment: Redirecting to another page terminates all JavaScript.

Comment: Code written after that is written for current page..Not for the page on which user is redirected...

Comment: Maybe this question will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048338/how-can-i-execute-a-script-after-calling-window-location-href

Comment: I know it terminates it but I don't want the changes to occur as soon as second page loads. I want the changes to take place only after button is pressed from page1

Comment: Cant you same some variables or send variables in an html message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of hit and trial I was able to achieve what I wanted. I redirected from one page to another but I added a string to the url of second page.

```
function myFunction() {

window.location.href = "html2.html?sound";
}
```

Then in the second page I called the function only if the url contains a certain word.
    function myFunc2(){

```
var url = document.URL;
url = url.split('?');
console.log(url[1]);
var temp = url[1];
if(temp == "sound") {
    console.log("sada");
    var button  = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "hello";
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(button);
 }
}
```

The function is called everytime the page loads but only adds button if the url contains "sound" word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute codes in the second page by passing some sort of flags i.e. via URL parameters and on load of second page check for if values exists then execute the fucntions