# Using JS inside PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to redirect a page with PHP and JS and also change the HTML upon redirection.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "http://example.com/#footer";
           document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "<h2>Thanks for the message. I will contact you shortly.</h2>";
      </script>';
```

The first part with the redirection is working, but the second where I try to change the DOM structure does not. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: make sure the dom is loaded before getelementbyid and maybe switch the order of the two statements

Comment: That would never work. The first line of JS gets executed and redirects the page and the second is lost forever and never encountered.

Comment: I don't think anything will run following the `window. location` command on the calling script.  See: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048338/how-can-i-execute-a-script-after-calling-window-location-href&ved=0ahUKEwiF6qO5gtHQAhUDJiYKHX-oCHMQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNEDOFLf4V-ChOjdtMIEx7j_cAhwlw&sig2=NmHsdfxIvK5l4xhjwkG35A

Comment: The PHP is entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: @Quentin PHP is not irrelevant. this is just a part of a code.